# nHibernate QueryOver with a Left Join using *OR* and *AND* clauses

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

After some hours looking for the answer I failed. Maybe is too simple and no one had never talked about it, maybe I didn't used the right terms to search.

Basically I need to use OR and AND clause on a LEFT JOIN table. And I wish to do that in a QueryOver. The resulting SQL should look like this:

```
SELECT customer.name, order.id
  FROM customer
  LEFT JOIN order ON (order.idcustomer = customer.id)
 WHERE customer.active
   AND (order.id IS NULL or (order.date >= :p0 AND order.date <= :p1)
```

Wich means, all active customers and their orders, BUT only those who never made an order or those who have orders between a specific period.

The most close to this I got in QueryOver was:

```
Order order = null;

var query = session.QueryOver<Customer>()
   .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Orders, () => order)
   .Where(x => x.Active)
   .And(() => order == null || (order.date >= date1 && order.date <= date2))
```

The above QueryOver, before even is executed, gives me 'Reference not set'. I found the instructions about using 'Restrictions', but none (or at least, none clear enought to my limited mind) using OR and AND togheter.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just missing a `.Id` on `order` in your where clause:

```
Order order = null;

var query = session.QueryOver<Customer>()
   .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Orders, () => order)
   .Where(x => x.Active)
   .And(() => order.Id == null || (order.date >= date1 && order.date <= date2))
// -----------------^
```

This gives me the following SQL (SQL Server):

```sql
SELECT
    this_.Name as y0_,
    order1_.Id as y1_ 
FROM
    Customer this_ 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Order] order1_ ON this_.Id = order1_.CustomerId
WHERE
    this_.Active = @p0 AND (
        order1_.Id IS NULL OR (
            order1_.Date >= @p1 AND order1_.Date <= @p2
        )
    );
```

Comment: Yeah! It works! I tried that before but since C# compiler keep saying "order.Id == null" will be always false because "Id" is a long, I thought woudn't not work (and didn't try).

Comment: @RogerKiihl: Ahh, yeah that makes sense. Fortunately the expressions QueryOver uses aren't actually evaluated at runtime, they're just parsed and ultimately turned into SQL, so it's safe to ignore those types of warnings here.